# Is it possible to prove A intersect C union B intersect C is equal to A union B intersect C using only set identities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm doing a problem in set theory where I have to prove that two statement are equivalent. The problem states that I'm only allowed to use set identities, but I'm stuck at a specific point and I don't know how to continue.

I need to prove that:

$A\cap C\cup B\cap C = (A\cup B) \cap C$

And I'm not sure how to do that with only the set identities. The distributive laws are very similar, but my case is missing parentheses, which I'm assuming means I can't use those laws here.

The original problem I need to solve:

$(A^c \cup B)\cap (B\cup C)\cap (C \cup A) = (A^c \cup B)\cap (C \cup A)$

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Usually, when parentheses are omitted, authors are following  a convention about operator precedence  (typically that $\cap$ binds tighter than $\cup$ so $A \cap B \cup B \cap C$ means $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C)$). Your testbook or teacher should have stated what conventions are in use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

$A \cap C \cup B\cap C$

$C \cap ((A \cap C) \cup B) $

$(C \cap (A \cap C))\cup (B \cap C)$

$(A \cap C)\cup (B \cap C)$

Use the distributive laws

$(A \cup B) \cap C$

Comment: What law are you using in your first step? It's probably wrong to assume that the expression with no parentheses is meant to be read from left to right.